# 'data' is null or not an object IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I am transmitting message from an iframe to its parent page using `postMessage`. This is my code.
In iframe:

```
$(".history_date").click(function(event) {
  window.top.postMessage($(this).text(), "*");
});
```

In parent page:

```
$(function(){
window.onmessage = function(e){
    if(e.data){
        //do something
        
    }
};
});
```

It works well in Chrome, Firefox and IE9/10, but in IE8, the error indicates

> 'data' is null or not an object.

How to fix it?

Comment: *"**'data'** is null or not an object"*? Not `e`? Because your code is clearly testing `e.data` before trying to use it, and the test would be `false` if `data` were `null`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE8 *still* lacks DOM2 event attachment, still using the global `event` object rather than one it passes into event handlers. You've said the error is `'data' is null or not an object`, are you sure it's not `'e' is null or not an object`?

If it is, then this should fix it:

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
   e = e || window.event;
   if (e.data) {
       // ...
   }
};
```

On IE8 and earlier, no argument is passed into event handlers. Instead, you look at the global `event` variable (global variables are also properties of the `window` object). So on IE8 and earlier, `e` will be `undefined`, whereas on IE9+ and all other browsers, `e` will be the event object.

So this line:

```
e = e || window.event;
```

...uses [the curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html), which will return its first argument if that argument is "truthy," or its second argument if the first is "falsey." Since `undefined` is falsey, on IE8 and earlier, `e = e || window.event` assigns `window.event` to `e`. On IE9+ and all other browsers, it just assigns `e` back to itself (a no-op).

This is a common pattern in code that has to interact with both IE8 and earlier and browsers that pass the event object into the handler.

Comment: Cool! It's fixed by your answer. Can you explain what "e = e || window.event;" do actually? I am new to javascript and jquery. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Leoest: Glad that helped. I've edited the answer to explain that line more.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That really helps a lot!! Thank you! I am eager to vote up but this new account cannot do that. You are really a cool guy!

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` is not supported in older version of IEs.  Try removing the line

```
console.log("message get: "+ e.data);
```

Comment: @user1900888 what does `e` contains?

Comment: @ user: IE8 has `console.log`, if you open dev tools. (It doesn't if you don't.)

Comment: Nothing else. I didn't specify e.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder previously he had this code in his question.  But he changed it seems.  When we open the console it works else IE will stop further execution of code.  Is that right?

Comment: @user1671639 yeah you are right. console.log has problem before, but I have fix it by adding the code you provide. The problem is about e.data now.

Comment: @user1900888: Please don't change questions such that you invalidate correct answers. Post a *new* question if the answer to a previous one solves *that* problem, but reveals a new one. (+1 to user1671639 for fixing his previous problem.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I will pay attention next time. But I have solved that problem before posting this question in fact. I have find solution in another comment in stack overflow. user1671639 just offer the same answer. But still thank you!